# Postfix and amavisd-new Bouncing and undelivered (queued) emails

Tags: queue, postfix-mta, postfix-notation, postfix-operator

So Postfix stopped delivering emails to inbox after a few hundred successfully were received/delivered. Now they are all landing in queue (postqueue -p). I had a high number of emails coming in from different sources for resume applications sent out. Recieved well over 100 perfectly, than all of a sudden no longer receiving any, and can no longer send any.

Server: Postfix, amavisd-new, SPAMASSASSIN,
CLAMAV, dovecot, nginx, debian9, roundcube, ispconfig.

It seems there is a long delay with the smtpd from the tail outputted below?

### All emails are landing in queue.

Here is some crucial tail information (in no particular order):

> postfix/qmgr[20034]: 84282221D5: from=, size=95838, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> postfix/smtpd[20067]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mx0a-0xxxx1.pxxxxxd.com[148.163.156.64]: : Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=
>
> postfix/smtp[20789]: 84282221D5: to=, relay=none, delay=1150, delays=1150/0.04/0.01/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
>
> postfix/qmgr[20034]: F14D9221D7: from=, size=44589, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> 17115 Wed Jun  5 18:16:40  noreply@dxxx---sender_email---xxxxe.com
>   (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
>
> postfix/anvil[20066]: statistics: max connection rate 2/60s for (smtp:185.137.111.96) at Jun  6 14:26:21
>   Jun  6 14:36:03 nychost postfix/anvil[20066]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:185.137.111.125) at Jun  6 14:26:09
>   Jun  6 14:36:03 nychost postfix/anvil[20066]: statistics: max message rate 1/60s for (smtp:148.163.156.64) at Jun  6 14:32:29
>   Jun  6 14:36:03 nychost postfix/anvil[20066]: statistics: max cache size 5 at Jun  6 14:29:24

---

Already tried postfix flush, postfix restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Seems it is fixed now. Fixed it myself.

sudo /etc/init.d/amavis restart

sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart

Comment: Damn im awesome